Is there a way to assign data in a set in Excel and operate on it?
I am an amateur at excel and wanted to know this thing for shortening my office work.
Say I have 6 Conditions to make and they have varying names
Cond 1  ---   A  D  C
Cond 2  ---   D  A
Cond 3  ---   B  A  C
Cond 4  ---   B  C
Cond 5  ---   A  C  D
Cond 6  ---   C B  D
I wanted to know a function that will consider A,B,C,D as a collection so i can operate on them.I want to then assign them numbers, and give an output of each Condition as a string of numbers and then check whether any of those is repeating or not. Order doesn't matter, as long as that combination of numbers repeat, some indication will be given out.
I am stuck at the part of taking it into a group like Sets in Maths. As for outputting the letter as a number i feel like IF will be used, but i will need to experiment a bit once i can form the set.

Can you provide us with a data sample, a desired output and how you got there, in text format? preferably using Table Markdown.

The question is a bit vague but I assume you could for condition1 :
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A2,D2,C2)

Assume you in B1 have the result of a 3 number condition.
C1: =MIN(MID(B1, 1, 1), MID(B1, 3, 1), MID(B1, 5, 1))
D1: =MEDIAN(MID(B1, 1, 1), MID(B1, 3, 1), MID(B1, 5, 1))
E1: =MAX(MID(B1, 1, 1), MID(B1, 3, 1), MID(B1, 5, 1))

Then in F1 you put:
=C1 & D1 & E1

Naturally you build this down for each condition.
Then in the G column: X = last row number in list
G1: =IF(COUNTIF(F$1:FX, F1)>1, "Duplicate", "Unique")
G2: =IF(COUNTIF(F$1:FX, F2)>1, "Duplicate", "Unique")
G3: =IF(COUNTIF(F$1:FX, F3)>1, "Duplicate", "Unique")


Basically assigning my inputs as numbers 1,2,3,...etc and putting them in a string say 123..etc.
Then passing the conditions through a function as follows:
The full set now is 1234
And my conditions go like
Condition 1 143
Condition 2 41
Condition 3 213
Condition 4 23
Condition 5 134
Now Conditions 1 and 5 are repeating but order wise they will appear as separate numbers to excel. Need a function or consecutive string of functions to make this happen.
I know this will involve a ton of functions but I want to learn how to do that.
